# Is the inverse of a truncated matrix the same as the truncation of the inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:

- $A \in \mathbb{R}^{D\times D}$ as a symmetric, square, positive definite, non-singular matrix
- $\Delta := A^{-1}$

Is the following statement true?

$(A_{d:,d:})^{-1} = \Delta_{d:,d:}$

Or in words, is truncating and finding the inverse identical to finding the inverse and then truncating?

**Note about abused subindex notation**: $A_{:,i}$ means the $i^{th}$ column,  $A_{i, :}$ the $i^{th}$ row and $A_{i:, j:}$ the submatrix resulting from starting at the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column (included).

---

Bonus questions:

- If the equality holds, would it hold for any $A_{d1:d2, d3:d4}$ submatrix?
- What would be the case if any of the $A$ features change? (asymmetric, semidefinite, rectangular, singular or quasi-zero eigenvalues...)

Cheers!
Andres

Comment: What is $\ \Sigma\ $ in the second bullet point? Do you mean $\ \Delta= A^{-1}\ $?  And does $\ \left(A_{d:,d:}\right)\ $ signify the last $\ D-d+1\ $ rows and columns of $\ A\ $, or the first $\ d\ $ rows and columns (or something else entirely)?

Comment: Yes sorry, originally it is a cov. matrix that's why I used $\Sigma$ but I changed the notation for more general clarity. Fixed. The abused subindex notation: $A_{:,d}$ is the $d^{th}$ column,  $A_{d, :}$ the $d^{th}$ row and $A_{d:, d:}$ all the rows and columns starting from (and including) the $d^{th}$ ones.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera edited the post with the clarification.

Comment: $(A^{-1})_{pp}=(A_{pp}-A_{pq}A_{qq}^{-1}A_{qp})^{-1}$, where $p,q$ are index sets that combine to make 1:n. Look into Schur complements.

Comment: @NickAlger you made my day with this amazing answer! It covers all my questions, including the extra ones, so if you want to post it as an answer I will be glad to accept it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad that helped. I don't want to take away from the answer that is already accepted so I will leave it as a comment

Comment: I understand. in any case I feel that Schur complement is exactly and essentially what the question is about, and am glad you mentioned it. Maybe I will elaborate an answer myself on that if you won't. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Nick Alger](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3060/nick-alger) pointed out (big thanks to him), **the relation between a truncated matrix and its inverse is regulated by the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)**, as follows:

If we partition a matrix $A$ into four submatrices as follows,

$
A =\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$

The inverse can be expressed as follows:

$
\Delta := A^{-1} =\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta_{11} & \Delta_{12} \\
\Delta_{21} & \Delta_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
(\frac{A}{A_{22}})^{-1} & (\frac{A}{A_{22}})^{-1} A_{12} (A_{22})^{-1}  \\
(A_{22})^{-1} A_{21} (\frac{A}{A_{22}})^{-1} & (\frac{A}{A_{11}})^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$

Where the fractions express the so-called Schur complements of their respective blocks:

$
\frac{A}{A_{22}} = A_{11} - A_{12} (A_{22})^{-1}A_{21} = (\Delta_{11})^{-1}\\
\frac{A}{A_{11}} = A_{22} - A_{21} (A_{11})^{-1}A_{12} = (\Delta_{22})^{-1}
$

- Especially note that in general the following is **not** true: $(A_{ij})^{-1} = \Delta_{ij}$.
- Also note that this will hold for any submatrix, since the rows and columns can be "shuffled" at convenience.

---

Further properties:

- If $A$ is non-singular, this works both ways (i.e. $A$ and $\Delta$ can be swapped above). If $A$ or $A_{22}$ are singular, the generalized Schur complement can be applied.
- $det(A) = det(A_{22}) det(\frac{A}{A_{22}})$
- If $A$ is symmetric, so is its inverse. The $M_{ii}$ partitions will be symmetric and $M_{ij} = M_{ji}^T$.
- If $A$ is positive definite, so will be $\Delta$ and any $M_{ii}$ partition.

---

I think that summarizes pretty much all the questions I had on the matter!
Cheers
Andres

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is no. Let  $\ A=\pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}\ $.  Then $\ \Delta=A^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&2}\ $, $\left(A_{2:,2:}\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\ne\ \Delta_{2:,2:}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\ $.

**Reply to questions:** I have to confess that since the statement didn't seem likey to me to be true, I didn't read through your calculations very carefully. That said, I didn't pick up any errors either.

The example I gave was a special case of $\ A=I_D + aa^\top\ $, which has inverse $\ \Delta=I_D-\frac{aa^\top}{1+a^\top a}\ $.  For this more general case $\ A_{d:,d:}=I_{D+1-d}+a_{d:} a^\top_{d:}\ $, which has inverse $\ \left(A_{d:,d:}\right)^{-1}=I_{D+1-d}-\frac{a_{d:} a^\top_{d:}}{1+a^\top_{d:}a_{d:}}\ $, while $\ \Delta_{d:,d:}=I_{D+1-d}-\frac{a_{d:} a^\top_{d:}}{1+a^\top a}\ $. So, in this case, there is indeed a fairly simple relation between $\ \left(A_{d:,d:}\right)^{-1}\ $ and $\ \Delta_{d:,d:}\ $, namely,
$$ \left(1+a^\top_{d:}a_{d:}\right)\left(I_{D+1-d}-\left(A_{d:,d:}\right)^{-1}\right)= \left(1+a^\top a\right)\left(I_{D+1-d}-\Delta_{d:,d:}\right)$$